# What is the simplest way to attach a node configuring kubelet?

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

I have created these files *ca.cert* and *kubelet.service* (systemd file with apiserver's IP and options). How can I simply add this new node to the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

To do this in the latest version (tested on 1.12) you can issue following command on the master node:

```
kubeadm token create --print-join-command
```

It will then print out a new join command (like the one you got after kubeadmn init):

```
kubeadm join 192.168.1.101:6443 --token tokentoken.lalalalaqyd3kavez --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:complexshaoverhere
```

Now run the above command on worker node, it must have docker, kubelet and kubeadm installed. You will be able to join the worker node.

Refer this official document [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your help and time. But is that necessary to use kubeadm? Is that possible to only use kubelet?